# mouse over image to display its enlarged image in a slider and all images in the slider on the right part of page

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, jquery-hover, mousehover

i did tried everything know am dried :( mouse over an thumbnail image display it should enlarger  image on rest of the page. if i swap between image that image should be enlarge. there are 3 images i.e., 2 thumbnails and a main image in a lil big img let say " I ", which on the left part of the page, when I  mouseover or hover on "I "it should display me an enlarged image on right in a slider containing 3 image when clicked on side arrow should display one image at a time    ... I hope I have clarified

```
<style>

.product .content .imgdiv .bottlesWrapper .ablahh{
 position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
 }

   .product .content .imgdiv .bottlesWrapper .ablahh:hover{
  background-color: transparent;
     z-index: 50;
    }

     .product .fltimg .thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
   width:200px;
 height:200px;
  position: absolute;
 background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
border: 1px dashed gray;
 visibility: visible;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  .product .fltimg .thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
 }

    .product  .fltimg .thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
 visibility: visible;
   top:10px;
  left: 60px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */

  }


 </style>
```

```
 <div class="fltimg">
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><span>
<img id="largeImage" src="images/1.jpg"/></span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

 <div class="imgdiv">
      <div class="bottlesWrapper">
     <a href="#" class="ablahh">
    <img id="blah" class="i1" src="#" width="115px" height="120px"/></a>

    </div>


 <div class="thumbs">
   <a href="#" class="ablah1">  <img id="blah1" class="i2" src="#" width="50px" height="20px"/></a>
      <a href="#" class="ablah2"><img id="blah2" class="i3" src="#" width="50px" height="20px"/></a>
    </div>
     </div>
   <!-- <a href="#" class="ablah"> <span> <img id="blah0" class="i11" src="#" width="500px"       height="300px"/> </span> </a>-->


<div class="title4">
<input class="file" name="logo" type="file"/>
</div>

<div class="title4">

    <input class="file1" id="files1" name="files1" type="file" />

</div>

<div class="title4">
    <input class="file2" id="files2" name="files2" type="file"/>

</div>

</div>
```

Please let me know how should i achieve this. I am losing my mind on this. :(  Thank you

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Please click here http://jsfiddle.net/Kk5ke/

Comment: the enlarged image slider should  overlay on the right  part and not over the image and thumbnail displayed

Comment: jsfiddle not uploading images............ but the same code uploads images from my system ......... i dont know whats going wrong

Comment: initial thumbnail in left:-1000px position then how can i hover it..?in which class we have to mouserhover

Comment: the thing is i have no idea ..... as a newbei  ... we have to mouserhover in class="i1" @manoj

Comment: This seems really complicated and I'm still not sure what you're asking.  You want an image to get bigger when you hover over it?  Is there any way to narrow the jsfiddle down to just the relevant code?  Are the examples on other sites of what you'd like to do?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed i have update the jsfiddle ......... with respective to the divs fltimg  overlays other 3 div which is not what i want.the thing is div fltimg  must be slider (with one image displayed at a time and the slider must have back and previous arrow css designed not buttons to display the next and previous images)enlarged to the right of div imgdiv ,div fltimg should have a transparent background and overlay over right side ... something relevant to z-index ...... but am unable to figure out..... please let me know ........ I hope you are clear for know ....thanx